# Opening a file and finding lines that have a "WORD" like GREP -w

Tags: c, grep, gnu

I am trying to scan through a file and print the lines having matching strings and words

If you have seen grep and its function -w it searches for words not strings by themselves

This is my code for the basic grep functionality. I first take the arguments in main and then pass the filename and etc to a function that has many conditions like this
(THIS IS FOR ALL MATCHING STRINGS NOT WORDS)!

```
if(grep_h==1 && grep_i==1  && (grep_w==0 && grep_c==0 && grep_m==0 && grep_b==0))
{
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))   //Reads the line from file
    {
        count=0;
        if(strcasestr(line, pattern)==NULL)    //Checks whether the given string is within the file or not
            continue;
        lineptr = line;
        ptr=strcasestr(lineptr, pattern);
        while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
            count = 0;
            pos = ptr - lineptr;     //This code collectively gets the position of the substring in a line repeatedly
            for(i=0;i<pos;i++)
            {
                putchar(lineptr[i]);
                count++;
            }

            for(i=0;i<strlen(pattern);i++)
            {
                printf(RED "%c", ptr[i]);
                count++;
                printf(RESET "");
            }

            lineptr= lineptr + count;             //Moves the line pointer ahead so as to find more occurences of the string
            ptr=strcasestr(lineptr,pattern);
        }
        printf("%s", lineptr);
    }

}
```

I don't know how to match the same thing for words
Words have non alphabetical beginnings and ends. How do I achieve this?

Eg.
Beginning of File
WORD wordwoordqordwododknd WORD WORD WORD
it should print the capital word (I made them capital because they matched the criteria)

Okay so I will post some concrete examples of what I'm trying to achieve

### Let this be the file

hello world ------------- this line will be printed and Hello will be highlighted

hello will be the key phrase here ---------- this line will also be printed and hello will be highlighted

nothello here ----Here hello is not an independent word so it will not be printed

nothello but hello world ---------the first hello is not a word but the second one is a word so it will be printed and only the second hello is highlighted

---

What my code currently does it that it finds strings within a given line

meaning that even that last line, the first hello would be highlighted even though it is not an independent word.

in pseudo code it would look like

```
read a line from a file
    if the given string is present in the line
           print it and move ahead in the string
           keep repeating above two steps until there is no more occurence of given string within line
```

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: I have posted an example of what I mean, sorry for not making it clear!

Comment: But you didn't read the link in my first comment...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, is this okay now?